# Set a custom file name to the export function of a Syncfusion grid view using Angular

Tags: angular, gridview, filenames, syncfusion

I have been using [this](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.1.32/angular/documentation/grid/excel-exporting.html) Syncfusion grid view in my Angular (v6.8) application.
All I want to achieve is to show a custom file name when the grid content is being downloaded as an excel sheet. currently. the file name is shown as "Export.xlsx" once it downloaded.

I went through [this](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/excel-exporting/#file-name-for-exported-document) documentation (it is a slightly different version) and it clearly explains how to set a file name. Unfortunately, when I try to repeat the same in the version that I am currently using ("@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids": "^16.1.48"), `ExcelExportProperties` doesn't recognize it as a valid property.

PS: I am adding the following source code for your reference

**SpecialistAssessmentReportsComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService, IspecialistAssessmentReport } from '../services/dashboard.service';
import { GridComponent, ToolbarItems, PdfExportProperties, ExcelExportProperties, FilterService, ToolbarService, ExcelExportService, SortEventArgs, PdfExportService, RowSelectEventArgs, SelectionSettingsModel, ToolbarItem, GroupSettingsModel, GridLine } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids';
import { ClickEventArgs } from '@syncfusion/ej2-navigations';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FrameworkConfigService } from '../../fw/services/framework-config.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-specialist-assessment-reports',
  templateUrl: './specialist-assessment-reports.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./specialist-assessment-reports.component.scss']
})

export class SpecialistAssessmentReportsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private configService: FrameworkConfigService,
    private dashboardService: DashboardService) { }

  public specialistAssessmentReportData: Array<IspecialistAssessmentReport>;

  specialistAssessmentReportGridId = 'specialistAssessmentReportGrid';
  @ViewChild('specialistAssessmentReportGrid')
  public specialistAssessmentReportGrid: GridComponent;

  public toolbar: ToolbarItems[];
  public filterSettings: Object;

  pdfexportproperties: PdfExportProperties;
  excelexportproperties: ExcelExportProperties;

  public gridFilterSettings = {}
  gridLines: GridLine = "Both";
  public gridPageSettings = {
    currentPage: 1,
    enableQueryString: true,
    pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100, 250],
    pageSize: 50
  };

  gridToolbarClick(args: ClickEventArgs) {
    if (args.item.id === (this.specialistAssessmentReportGridId + '_excelexport')) {
      this.specialistAssessmentReportGrid.excelExport(this.excelexportproperties);
    }
    if (args.item.id === (this.specialistAssessmentReportGridId + '_pdfexport')) {
      this.specialistAssessmentReportGrid.pdfExport(this.pdfexportproperties);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.specialistAssessmentReportAuthorized()) {
      this.redirectToHome();
      return;
    }

    this.toolbar = ["ExcelExport", "Search"];
    this.gridFilterSettings = { type: 'Excel' };
    this.dashboardService.getspecialistAssessmentReport().subscribe(data => {
      this.specialistAssessmentReportData = data;
    });
  }

  specialistAssessmentReportAuthorized(): boolean {
    let authorized: boolean = false;

    if (this.authService.isAdministrator() || this.authService.isVsbaRFE()) {
      authorized = true;
    }
    return authorized;
  }

  redirectToHome(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }    
}
```

**SpecialistAssessmentReportsComponent.html**

```
<div class="col-12" style="min-height:660px">
  <app-sectiontitle [heading]="'Specialist assessment activity report'"></app-sectiontitle>
  <p>Use the grid below to view the specialist assessment activity report. You can filter, sort, group, export and search using the grid below.</p>
  <div class="empty20"></div>
  <!-- Grid -->
  <div id="gridContainer">
    <ejs-grid #specialistAssessmentReportGrid id="specialistAssessmentReportGrid" [dataSource]="specialistAssessmentReportData"
              [allowSorting]="true" [allowGrouping]="true" [allowExcelExport]="true" [allowTextWrap]="true"
              [toolbar]="toolbar" [allowPdfExport]="true"
              [allowFiltering]="true" [filterSettings]="gridFilterSettings"
              [allowPaging]="true" [pageSettings]="gridPageSettings"
              [gridLines]="gridLines"
              (toolbarClick)="gridToolbarClick($event)">
      <e-columns>
        <e-column width="7%" field="schoolNumber" headerText="School number" [allowGrouping]="false" [allowFiltering]="true"></e-column>
        <e-column width="20%" field="schoolName" headerText="School name" [allowGrouping]="false" [allowFiltering]="true"></e-column>
        <e-column width="20%" field="activity" headerText="Activity" [allowGrouping]="true" [allowFiltering]="true"></e-column>
        <e-column width="25%" field="additionalInfo" headerText="Additional info" [allowGrouping]="true" [allowFiltering]="true"></e-column>
        <e-column width="10%" field="createdByName" headerText="Actioned by" [allowGrouping]="true" [allowFiltering]="true"></e-column>
        <e-column width="10%" field="createdOn" headerText="Activity date" [allowGrouping]="true" [allowFiltering]="true">
          <ng-template #template let-data>
            {{data.createdOn| date:'dd/MM/y HH:mm'}}
          </ng-template>
        </e-column>
        <e-column width="8%" field="dayDifference" headerText="Days b/w activities" [allowGrouping]="true" [allowFiltering]="true"></e-column>
      </e-columns>
    </ejs-grid>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="empty40"></div>
```

[image]

According to the snapshot above, 'fileName' seems not a valid property in the *excelexportproperties* object. I made the object as 'any' (without specifying it as a '`ExcelExportProperties`' type of object) as you have done in your sample code. Then it was complaining as *"ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'fileName' of undefined"*

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared a sample in the following stackblitz link but we are unable to reproduce the issue from our end.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlmwxa?file=package.json

So, please provide the following details for better assistance.

Share the screen shot or video demonstration of the issue.
Share the stack trace detail if you face any script error in console window.
Share the complete Grid code example.
If possible please try to reproduce the issue in the attached sample.

Regards, 
Thavasianand S.

Comment: Please read my question again. I have added the source code and modified it. Thank you very much for your concern.